Azure DevOps access and license management via RBAC
I have some questions about user management in Azure DevOps.
There are more than 500+ users in my organization. Previously, most of the users were added manually to Azure DevOps and it is frustrating to manage the users. I have a task to use RBAC for this. Couldn't find a proper solution on the internet. Hense thought to post here.
Entra ID and Azure DevOps are connected.
I have created 3 groups in Entra ID to assign the licenses and 1 group to manage Visual Studio license holders.
#G-StakeholderLincese 
#G-BasicLincese 
#G-Basic&TestPlansLincese 
#G-VSLicenseHolders
My question is how can I grant each access levels to users? 
I can find the group through "search groups".

Is it correct, if I add the group as below?



AD Group
Access Level
Azure DevOps Groups




#G-StakeholderLincese
Stakeholder
Project Reader


#G-BasicLincese
Basic
Project Contributor


#G-Basic&TestPlansLincese
Basic + Test Plans
Project Contributor


#G-VSLicenseHolders
Basic
Project Contributor



The other question is,
When I created and added the AD group to a project, it doesn't show my project name under "Username, Scope or App Id" and shows as "TEAM FOUNDATION". Is there any way that I can change this to my Project name or is this is an as build name? Please see the image

Really appreciate any guidance. Thanks a lot.


My question is how can I grant each access levels to users?

You are doing in correct way.
When you add a new group rule, you can assign the access level to the whole AAD group.
The project reader, project contributor is project membership which based on project, you need to pick the project and set the membership on target project.

Need to mention is, for Visual Studio Subscribers, it works different. Please check the link below for the details.

Please note: The users from group rule don't appear in All users until they attempt to sign in for the first time.
Please refer to the doc Assign access levels with group rules for more details.

When I created and added the AD group to a project, it doesn't show my project name under "Username, Scope or App Id" and shows as "TEAM FOUNDATION". Is there any way that I can change this to my Project name or is this is an as build name?

It's designed behavior, and correctly there's no way to change "Username, Scope or App Id" value as project name or build name. The TEAM FOUNDATION is specific for AAD group.

Thanks a lot for the advice, Wade. Would you be able to explain more about how can I manage VS license holders in ADO? Thanks.

Thanks @KalanaD. For VS license holders, you can still do with basic access level and project contributor as you did above. When the user login in, it will show as direct access level in user list. DevOps will automatically do for you.
